# Jquery, ajax button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button that submit data via ajax. Then when I have it change to a different button which then creates a cycle between the two buttons.

However the second button isn't click-able. Any idea why? Heres my code:

```
<div class="<?PHP echo $value['id'];?>"><button class="checkin" id="<?PHP echo $value['id'];?>">Checkin</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // wrap inside the jquery ready() function


//Attach an onclick handler to each of your buttons that are meant to "approve"
$(".checkin").click(function(){

   //Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");


   $.ajax({
      url: "checkin_user.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "POST",
      data: "eventid=<?PHP echo $eventId;?>" + "&id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, //The data your sending to some-page.php
      success: function(){
          alert("AJAX request was successfull");
          $("." + id_of_item_to_approve).html('<button class="checkout" id="' + id_of_item_to_approve + '">Check Out</button>');
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }   
    });

});

//Attach an onclick handler to each of your buttons that are meant to "approve"
$(".checkout").click(function(){

   //Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");


   $.ajax({
      url: "checkin_user.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "POST",
      data: "checkout=1&eventid=<?PHP echo $eventId;?>" + "&id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, //The data your sending to some-page.php
      success: function(){
          alert("AJAX request was successfull");
          $("." + id_of_item_to_approve).html('<button class="checkin" id="'+ id_of_item_to_approve +'">Check In</button>');
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }   
    });

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Search for delegated event handlers. Or look at http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your button is dynamically generated from ajax response, you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkout', function() {
    //rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: The reasoning behind is as follows: "dynamically generated tags are not visible to Javascript running unless you are using .on method.The method is constantly monitoring for new items added to DOM."

Comment: do i wrap that around my entire code? or just the checkout handler function?

Comment: @user2570937 you can use above code for elements that are generated dynamically & need to attach event handler, not for all the code you have. In your case it would be needed only for ".checkout" button. btw, it would be better if you read the docs so that you get a clear idea of why your code didnt work and what should be done instead. That would help you in future as well..

Answer (score 1):

Because you missed two things:

1. Enable on click event for document to monitor button.check* is clicked.
2. New `.checkout` button you are appending inside exiting `.checkin` button using `html()`. This should be replaced.

**Here I'm describing:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkin', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Ajax block
  $("#" + id_of_item_to_approve).replace('<button class="checkout" id="' + id_of_item_to_approve + '">Check Out</button>');
  // End Ajax block
});

$(document).on('click', '.checkout', function(e) {
  ...
});
```